# IBM Watson Assistant Endpoint URL does not work anymore for Alexa Skill. Alexa can't reach Endpoint

Tags: https, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alexa-skills-kit, watson-assistant

I've created an Watson Assistant and pasted the OpenWhisk Action Endpoint URL to my Alexa Skill as described in this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/IBM/alexa-skill-watson-assistant).

Everything worked fine so far. I was able to send questions to my Chatbot by talking to the Alexa Simulator and received the expected answer which was read out by Alexa. But if I launch my Alexa skill now I get the response `"I am unable to reach the requested skill"`. The Endpoint URL is correct as well as the SSL Certificate Type Configuration in the Alexa Simulator. I did not change anything but suddenly it does not work but used to work fine before. Any ideas?

I tried to send the Launch Request as Manual JSON from the Alexa Simulator and received `"Cannot establish SSL connection to your skill endpoint"` as output JSON.
Furthermore I found the following from the Alexa Simulator logs:
`"The SSL handshake to endpoint Resource [https://eugb.functions.appdomain.cloud/api/v1/web/hhzStud_AIA_projekt/default/watson-alexa-hhz-skill.json], Type [HTTP], Region [DEFAULT] failed. Please check that your java keystore is correctly configured"`

I checked my acttion using the following command `ibmcloud fn activation list`  and got an application error ([IBM Docs Link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-limits#limits_fixed))

Why can't Alexa reach my Endpoint? It used to work before without any problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue between Alexa and the endpoint deployed on IBM Cloud. Make sure to use https://eu-gb.functions.appdomain.cloud and not https://eugb.functions.appdomain.cloud as listed in the description.

I can access https://eu-gb.functions.appdomain.cloud/api/v1/web/hhzStud_AIA_projekt/default/watson-alexa-hhz-skill.json and it uses a Let's Encrypt certificate with below details:
[image]

A similar issue was reported in https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/106526/getting-ssl-handshake-failed-error.html and a response pointed towards this list of requirements for your web service https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html#requirements-for-your-web-service.

Maybe it helps as a starting point to verify what is missing.

Comment: Hi Daniel,
thanks for your answer. I checked and again and I use https://eu-gb.functions.appdomain.cloud. So the URL is correct I had a typo in the description. I think the issue is with Alexa.

Comment: I take it as a test you have been able to call the cloud function via curl or postman? I have also in the past temporary redirected the call from Alexa to a Node Red Instance (on IBM's cloud), which allows me to view the details of the call, and check nothing changed.